# Elastic search 5.4 Update \ add nested document

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

```
{
        "id":100,
        "name":"xxx",
        "others":{
            "hobbies":["cricket","footbal"]
        }}
```

1. How to add new value in hobbies ("hobbies":["cricket","footbal","reading books"])
2. How add new field in others (ex : location)
3. How to remove "cricket from hobbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user `scripted update`([documentation link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)) for your requirement.

1. Query to **add value** in hobbiles

   ```
   {
       "script" : {
           "source": "ctx._source.others.hobbies.add(params.hobby)",
           "lang": "painless",
           "params" : {
           "hobby": "reading books"
        }
      }
   }
   ```
2. **Adding a new field in others**

   ```
   {
       "script": {
           "source": "ctx._source.others.location = 'value_of_new_field'",
           "lang": "painless"
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Remove** cricket from hobbies

   ```
   {
       "script" : {
           "source": "int index = ctx._source.others.hobbies.indexOf(params.remove_string); if(index != -1){ctx._source.others.hobbies.remove(index);}",
           "lang": "painless",
           "params" : {
               "remove_string" : "cricket"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

***UPDATE-1*** As per asked in comments below is way to add an array field.

*Adding an **array** field*

```
    {
        "script": {
            "source": "ctx._source.extra.location = []",
            "lang": "painless"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vinit. In Example #2 .. have to create like this "Location":[] - in the form of array. other #1 ,#3 is working fine..@vinit payal

Comment: Thanks a lot .. Posting another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926849/elastic-search-search-exact-matching-string-using-query-ui?noredirect=1#comment84859798_48926849

Comment: @LearnHadoop didn't you liked this answer ? If it solved your query where is upvote for it ? dude it can at least help other guys also to identify right answer ?

Comment: Yes.. It help others. Now i did