# Elastic search- search exact matching string using query UI

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

Here is my JSON .

```
{
    "id":100,
    "name":"xxx",       
    "hobbies":["cricket","footbal","singing & dancing"]

}
```

I need to filter "singing & dancing" string from "others".  Executed below query.

```
http://localhost:9200/employeed/data/_search?q={"query":{"query_string":{"query" : "hobbies:Singing & dancing"}}}
```

I am getting below exception.

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "request [employee/data/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [ Singing\"}}}]"
```

Any help?

Comment: close the brackets after "hobbies and reopen before singing. it's a key-value pair

Comment: Still getting the same exception. this is the query {"query":{"query_string":{"query" : "hobbies":"Singing & dancing"}}}

Comment: How are you running this? With curl? Or kibana? What's the "query UI"?

Comment: I am using Query UI

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to send a DSL query in a URI. The two don't mix, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-search.html

> The search API allows you to execute a search query and get back search hits that match the query. The query can either be provided using a simple query string as a parameter, or using a request body.

You can either use the DSL and send it in your request body, or change your URL to *just* include the hobbies query_string you want to use. Like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/employeed/data/_search?q=hobbies%3A%5C%22Singing%20%26%20dancing%5C%22
```

The query_string portion is also URL encoded. I've also added quotes around your search value, otherwise it will OR them together. The unencoded version:

```
hobbies:\"Singing & dancing\"
```

Comment: Still i am getting unrecognized parameter error .. the problem with & charater in query url ..is there anyother way to overcome this issue

Comment: My encoded URL solution doesn't have any ampersand in it. Additionally, I tried sending the DSL in a request body _with_ the ampersand and that works.

Comment: Would be great share code part. Since i am new to ES  and what is DSL.  Already they implemented using direct query. the problem with '&' char. Please share more additional information. thanks a lot